# How to create table from existing 2 table with default value in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, ddl

I want to create new table from existing 2 table selected column, with new column contain '99999999' like dummy value.

I tried below code

```
CREATE TABLE NewTbl1
AS 
    SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, b.col4, b.col5, dummycol= '99999999'
    FROM tbl1 a  tbl2 b 
    WHERE (a.col1 = b.colNum AND a.col2 = b.colnum1)
```

But I get an error that FROM keyword is not found. If I remove dummcol='99999999', then it executes properly.

Is it right query or wrong? If wrong please correct me

Comment: '99999999' as dummycol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use proper `join` syntax and use the right syntax for aliases:

```
CREATE TABLE NewTbl1 as 
    SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, b.col4, b.col5, '99999999' as dummycol
    FROM tbl1 a JOIN
         tbl2 b 
         ON a.col1 = b.colNum AND a.col2 = b.colnum1;
```

Comment: How would I give datatype to dummycol? coz its default take is characture But I want as number

Comment: You can use cast - `cast(99999999 AS number) as dummycol`

Comment: @dwan . . . Remove the single quotes -- 'm not sure if it will end up as a number or integer, though.  An explicit cast can be used to specify the type more specifically.

Comment: @Stawros- query run  but when I am going to open it, give me error that Conversion from "DBNULL" to "integer" is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE NewTbl1
AS 
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, b.col4, b.col5, '99999999' as dummycol
FROM tbl1 a, tbl2 b 
WHERE (a.col1 = b.colNum AND a.col2 = b.colnum1)
```